# Why two javascript date instance have different GMT?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, momentjs

I'm developing one web application using Asp.net MVC and Knockout.js and Moment.js library. I have one simple form that read two dates and perform one Ajax call.

This is my code:

```
<div id="graph-filters" >
   <input class="datepicker" data-bind="value: baseViewModel.dateFrom" />
   <input class="datepicker" data-bind="value: baseViewModel.dateTo" />
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: baseViewModel.loadData" value="Aggiorna" />
</div>

function loadData() {
var from = moment(this.dateFrom()).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
var to = moment(this.dateTo()).format("DD-MM-YYYY");

$.get("Home/GetData", { dateFrom: formatDate(from), dateTo: formatDate(to) }, function (result) {});
}
```

The problem is that when I pass the second line loadData function, the value of to variable is not correct. My expected value is 31/07/2016 (2016-07-31).

[image]

*Note: at this example I've inserted 01/07/2016 (2016-07-01) for dateFrom property and 31/07/2016 (2016-07-31) for dateTo property.*

How can I fix my problem?

EDIT: I have the same problem using this code:

```
function loadData() {
var from = new Date(this.dateFrom());
var to = new Date(this.dateTo());

$.get("Home/GetData", { dateFrom: formatDate(from), dateTo: formatDate(to) }, function (result) {});
}
```

The formatDate function convert the date in yyyy-mm-dd format. Below the code:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: I guess `baseViewModel.date` Should be  `baseViewModel.dateTo`

Comment: Sorry, bad copy paste 

Comment: what happens if you remove the momentjs calls - do you see expected dates then?

Comment: We'll need a repro, preferably a [mcve], not a screenshot of the debugger. Please also include what "not correct" means (what are the values *exactly*), and any relevant details about timezones and culture settings.

Comment: @G.Stoynev Hi, variable to is not correct also using this code: var to = new Date(this.dateTo()). I edit my question.

Comment: I was just curious to see what dates you get if you just use plain var to = this.dateTo(); Idea is to confirm your wiring is as expected, then move to debugging possible issues with the locale on the device.

Comment: Did my answer help? Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write your own date formatter, instead use JavaScript Date's [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method e.g.

```
function loadData() {
 var from = new Date(this.dateFrom());
 var to = new Date(this.dateTo());

 $.get("Home/GetData", 
       { 
        dateFrom: from.toISOString(), 
        dateTo: to.toISOString() 
       }, 
       function (result) {
         console.log(result);           
       });
}
```

Your MVC GET method will then be able to correctly interpret these dates.